# How to use jQuery.tmpl() plugin passing in just a string[], not an object

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a simple template I'm using a plug in ([Jquery.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)), and I want simply pass in an array of strings and setup my template to display those strings.  I've used these plenty passing in objects but I can't seem to find or figure out the syntax if you are not passing in an object and are just passing in a string.

Example:

```
var years = { 2011, 2012, 2013}

$.tmpl('blah', years).appendTo("#somediv");

$.template('blah', <div>(this is where I want the string value)</div>
```

So what is the syntax that I need to put in my template.

Comment: You guys are teaching me more about jQuery templates than I honestly ever wanted to know....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is actually {$data} which will give you the template item's value.

Took some serious searching by finally found it buried in the doc with no examples.

Comment: Any idea how to use {$data} to loop over the items in an {{each}} ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `years` has to be an array of objects. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var years = [{Year: 2011}, {Year: 2012}, {Year: 2013}]; // no quotes around "Year"
    $.template("blah", "<div>${Year}</div>"); // ${whatever name} becomes a value
    $.tmpl("blah", years).appendTo("#somediv");     
});
</script>

<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **${$data}** in your template definition to get the item itself